# Bug in the search for CRM Dynamics

Tags: search, settings, dynamics-crm

I have noticed in Microsoft CRM Dynamics that the search does not work properly. For instance, if I am in the **Active Contact view** and I look for any contacts by the first name sometimes it shows up. On the other hand sometimes it cannot find the contact however if I do look them up using their last name it finds them. I know for sure that the contacts are active because I can see them.

Can someone explain to me what is happening and why?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because everytime you enter in search box Quick Find View is used instead of your current. Check this article - http://crmbook.powerobjects.com/basics/searching-and-navigation/searching-crm/

Comment: This is good but still it does not solve the issue. Some contacts are not showing up in the search even though I am looking directly for them through the Quick Search. And they are Active contacts

Comment: Have you defined all the fields you want to check in Quick Find Fields?

Comment: Quick find uses Entities (limited to 10) and Contacts is one of those entities for me. Is there another place that I should be looking in?

Comment: I haven't mentioned Entities. I mentioned Fields. Check this article - https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/prashantshuklamscrm/archive/2015/02/26/adding-fields-to-quick-find-search-global-search-universal-search-result-in-ms-crm-2015

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem after launching Dynamics CRM 2015. Our consultant wrote a script to re-organize the search-indices in the CRM database. The DB-server runs the script in a weekly job and our seach works as expected.

Sorry, that my answer is not quite specific, but it should give you an idea. Try this link for a start: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn919650.aspx